# Persistent issues with installation of OpenAI gym

Tags: python, openai-gym

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and am having trouble doing a full installation of "gym".  What I did:

1. Installed Anaconda 4.2.0 (the version that comes with Python 3.5)
2. Installed dependencies with `sudo apt-get install -y python-numpy python-dev cmake zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev xvfb libav-tools xorg-dev python-opengl libboost-all-dev libsdl2-dev swig`
3. Cloned gym repository with "git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git"
4. Installed gym with `cd gym` and then `pip install -e '.[all]'`

I get no errors throughout this process.  Then I open the Spyder ide and run:

```
import gym

env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
```

And it works fine.  However, when I run

```
import gym

env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
```

I get the error:

```
/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Box2D/_Box2D.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_appendEPKcm
```

I also get errors when I try to access other box2d and atari environments.

It is also worth noting that I tried doing all of this on another virtual machine on which I installed the Python 2.7 version of Anaconda, and I got the same message...so this does not seem to have anything to do with the version of python I am using.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.

Try to install gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 in your conda environment with `conda install -c anaconda gcc=4.8.5`. This fixed it for me. See also https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gcc .

I had the same issue with my default gcc

`$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked for me. However, I had to remove the compiled wheel from the pip cache in order for it to be rebuilt, otherwise it just used the cached version instead. See pip caching info [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching).

Answer (score 2):

If you installed conda environment, use conda in your channel.

```
$ conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/kne pybox2d
```

Box2d will be added under `python3.5/site-packages`, and try code again.

```
import gym

env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
```

Good luck.